# CSS Transition apply to Elements being pushed

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've got (hopefully) a simple CSS problem, that I cannot get working.

If you go to http://new.therepairshack.com and take a look at the top search bar.

When you hover over it, it resizes to content width.

The CSS for this is here:

```
.header .search-wrapper .form-search .input-text {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color:#000;
    border-radius:0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #444;
}

.header .search-wrapper:hover,
.header .search-wrapper:hover .form-search,
.header .search-wrapper:hover form,
.header .search-wrapper:hover .input-text {
    width:100%;
    font-size:45px;
    height:100px;
}

.header .search-wrapper,
.header .search-wrapper form,
.header .search-wrapper .form-search,
.header .search-wrapper .input-text {
    transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    display:block;
}
```

Right now we're working on getting this functionality working in Chrome and Firefox. When I view it in chrome the background div instantly jumps to a larger height to fit the resized search bar, but when it resizes back down after you've left hover it does it smoothly.

My question: Is there any way to make the jumping go away? It's driving me nuts. I have added a transition to all of the elements that are moving when the search bar is being resized and that isn't working.

Also, what is the best way to get this working properly in other browsers? Thanks!!!

Let me know if you need anymore information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't transition from an undefined starting point.
You must either

Specify an initial height on your .search-wrapper 
http://jsfiddle.net/5h69j6uq/

Or, if your content must be dynamically sized, set the updated height by using the `min-height: 100px` property rather than the `height: 100px` property. `min-height` has a default value of 0 and will thus transition from that defined default value to 100px 
http://jsfiddle.net/8t1beeLo/

Answer (score 1):

You will have to manually set the height on the .header-top-container class and adjust it accordingly for the hover state.

CSS by standard will only apply animations to elements that are defined in rules to have them applied. And furthermore transitions will only be applied when there is a starting and end result, so **inferred** values such as height and width will not be animateable. Noticed I didn't say **inherited** values, as those technically have a starting value and therefore are animateable.

So for your CSS, you'll want something to this effect:

```
.header-top-container {
    transition: height 1.0s ease;
    -webkit-transition: height 1.0s ease;
    height: 50px; /* change to whatever your height should be */
}

.header-top-container:hover {
    height: 100px; /* the new height of the background */
}
```